# Add Visual State to nested controls with WPF 4

Tags: wpf, visualstatemanager

I'd like to know if is it possible to apply a Visual State (in WPF 4) to nested controls. I've got a stack panel that contains some elements I'd like to change according to variation state.

```
<StackPanel x:Name="panPremioRaggiunto">
 <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 <VisualStateGroup Name="StatiComuni">
 <VisualState Name="PremioNonRaggiunto" />
 <VisualState Name="PremioRaggiunto">
 <Storyboard>
  <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="lblPremioRaggiunto" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground" To="Green" />
 </Storyboard>
 </VisualState>
 </VisualStateGroup>
 </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
 <TextBlock x:Name="lblPremioRaggiunto">TEXT</TextBlock>
</StackPanel>
```

When I try to change the state of entire stack panel with this code

```
VisualStateManager.GoToState(panPremioRaggiunto, "PremioRaggiunto", False)
```

nothing happens: nested textblock named lblPremioRaggiunto don't change his color according. Can I apply a visual state in this manner?

Thanks,
Danilo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed issue: visual states are defined outside a control template so I have to use *VisualStateManager.GoToElementState* instead of *GoToState*.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, `VisualStateManager` can change the state of any control. You must have some other issue with your code.

Comment: I understood the issue.
I don't have to use _VisualStateManager.GoToState_ to change a state but _VisualStateManager.GoToElementState_ because visual states are defined outside a control template.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I totally forgot about that! You should add an answer yourself for anyone else who finds this question.